# Google.co.uk and https

Tags: google-search, https

Is it possible to search with google.co.uk with https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As typing "https://www.google.co.uk" just redirects to plain old "http://www.google.co.uk" I'd say you can't at the moment.

If you go to "https://www.google.com" you should notice that it says "beta" on the logo:

[image]

Therefore, I wouldn't expect it to be rolled out globally just yet. Once it leaves beta I'd hope that the country specific secure sites would become available.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.google.com/ should give you the same search results, with https.

Comment: uk specific results?

Comment: What results to you get at .co.uk that is missing from .com?

Comment: I was under the impression that co.uk gave higher rank to local sites otherwise wouldn't  a search for any general service (e.g. car insurance) always just give american results?